# What can be done to eliminate heel lift?

Tags: boots, footwear

The obvious answer is find a proper fitting boot, but what about those of us that are unfortunate enough to have improper fitting feet? I feel like a mutant sometimes because I have wide feet, huge heel spurs, really long toes, and skinny ankles. They almost resemble hands more than feet. I've been experimenting with insoles, socks and different ways of lacing an tightening my boots, but I still get heel lift, especially when toed in with crampons.

I have a feeling part of my problem is just having weak toes, but are there some tricks or products out there that help eliminate heel lift?

Comment: I struggled to find boots where heel lift wasn't a problem.  No help with your current boots, but for your next pair maybe look at Asolo or Salomon.  They work for me (narrow side-to-side but deep front-to-back heel cups compared with other brands).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One product, from [StopHeelLift.com](https://stopheellift.com/products/shl), consists of two pairs of sticky L-shaped pads. Note, it can only be used in boots with removable liners.

Comment: I went to that online store an bought two of every product they carry; the stop-heel-lifts (SHL), the heel raisers, and the volume reducers. They've worked great.

Comment: @ShemSeger: I am glad that it worked for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

When you buy a new shoe, it's very nice to have one with thermo fitting or foam fitting technology. (Scarpa, Dynafit, black diamond, Fischer, are a few brands that have shoes with this support.

What also helps if you have a Powerstrap (Velcro) and/or more than only one or two iron hoop to tight you boot. I've one with 4 and this works very well with my feet.

If you get blisters you can use neoprene ankle protectors like [eZeefit Ultrathin Ankle Booties](http://www.ezeefitsports.com/product-p/011.htm). They work also with wet feet and reduce the friction on your skin. It's probably much cheaper than buy new shoes. :)

[image]

And when you're climbing try to tight your shoes on top, that you don't loose them and still get blood circulation.